# Quartz Scheduler - cluster aware without database?

Tags: database, jdbc, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I need to use quartz scheduler in a clustered environment but we have no local database in which to manage JDBCJobStore.  This seems to be the only mechanism available to manage quartz over multiple servers other than possibly paying to use TerracottaJobStore which is not something we can do.

Does anyone know of any other options that are available for this situation?

Comment: Out of the box, no. Persistent job store is the only way to go in a clustered environment. If you want to avoid the DB, you will have to implement your own JobStore that gets automatically synched in your cluster through broadcast messages. I would not recommend using that.